# Python import function from package

Tags: python, python-3.x, package, python-import

*(Python 3.6)*

I have this folder structure:

```
package/
       start.py
       subpackage/
                 __init__.py
                 submodule.py
```

**submodule.py:**

```
def subfunc():
    print("This is submodule")
```

**__ init __.py:**

```
from subpackage.submodule import subfunc
```

**start.py:**

```
import subpackage 

subpackage.subfunc()

subpackage.submodule.subfunc()
```

I understand how and why

```
subpackage.subfunc()
```

works.

But I don't understand why:

```
subpackage.submodule.subfunc()
```

also works, if I have not done:

```
from subpackage import submodule
```

Nor:

```
import subpackage.submodule
```

Neither in **__ init __.py** nor in **start.py**

Thank you very much if anyone may clear my doubt.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When issuing `from subpackage.submodule import subfunc`, python does [two things](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html#the-import-system) for you: one, search and evaluate the module named `subpackage.submodule`, put it into `sys.modules` cache; two, populate `subpackage.submodule.subfunc` object and bind name "subfunc" to the namespace of the current module:

> The import statement combines two operations; it searches for the named module, then it binds the results of that search to a name in the local scope.

When importing `subpackage.submodule`, parent of `submodule` also got imported:

> While certain side-effects may occur, such as the importing of parent packages, and the updating of various caches (including sys.modules) ...

On the last stage of importing `subpackage.submodule`, python would set the module [as an attribute](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.6.3/Lib/importlib/_bootstrap.py#L956-L959) on its parent `subpackage`, this behavior is [documented](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html#submodules):

> When a submodule is loaded using any mechanism (e.g. importlib APIs, the import or import-from statements, or built-in __import__()) a binding is placed in the parent module’s namespace to the submodule object.

---

Comment: Hello georgexsh. I have not done "import subpackage.submodule" neither in "__ init __.py" nor  "start.py" . I imported the "subfunc()" into the namespace of " __ init __.py" and then imported the content of " __ init __.py" into start by importing "subpackage" into "start.py". The "func()" in "__ init __" should be a different object than the one in "submodule". That is my doubt.  Am I wrong?

Answer (score 0):

If I'm getting this right, you have a folder called "package" in which there are 2 *things*: a .py file and another folder called "subpackage".

Inside "subpackage" you have `__init__.py` and `submodule.py` which the latter contains a function that just prints "This is submodule".

Now, when you call `import subpackage`, you call and "pull" **everything** that's inside *"subpackage"*, including submodule and therefore, the `subfunc()` function.
When you write `subpackage.submodule.subfunc()` there's really nothing amazing going there, you just call the mainfolder/container **(subpackage.)**, then the .py file **(submodule.)** and finally the function itself **(subfunc() )**.

Comment: Hello Rolin. You got the strcture right. But this is the question:

Comment: Hello Rolin. You got the structure right. This is the doubt: in the "__init__.py" file the "subfuc()" function was imported into the namespace, which makes it accesible directly but not by referencing it with dot notation (since they are 2 different objects). When I imported the package "subpackage" into start.py,  the "start.py" have access to the content of  subpackage's __init__ file.  The statement "subpackage.submodule.subfunc()" in "start.py" is accesing the "func()" in "submodule.py" which should not be accesible since "submodule.py" was not imported into "start" nor "__init__".

Comment: Man, you are twisting your head around this simple problem ;)
The thing is, when you import `subpackage` in **start.py**, the **__init__.py** inside the subpackage tells `start.py` what is inside `submodule.py`, so it basically acts as an index for `start.py`.
Try commenting everything inside `__init__.py` and then executing `start` to see what I mean.

Comment: Rolin, thank you for your awnser. But I don't think you understand my question. When I import just a package, the content of its __init__ file is executed in the script importing the package. If the content of the __init__ (as in my example) just import an object from a module as in "from module import function object" , only the function object should be accesible to the __init__ and to the script importing the content of the __init__. The whole module to which the function object belong should not be accesible. That is my doubt.